# Cisco E3200 Router nor workong as it should

Tags: wireless-networking

I would appreciate some heads up in this matter, sorry for the long post but I want to explain as much as I can.

Ive recently bought a new mac retina display and an apple tv 3. Because of this i thought it would be a good idea to change my old router. After reading some reviews I decided to go for the Cisco Linksys E3200, my apt is not that big and we usually have all our networks devices in the living room. Only the mac and the apple tv3 would be on the wireless signal i have a ps3 and a sony tv connected directly by cable to the router.

When i bought the modem everything "SEEMED" to go good, i had a signal, i could browse and even tried the netflix app on the apple tv.

But I soon started to find problems with the connection. I first noticed it when i did some upgrading on my mac software.

So I could get online browse web pages, but everytime i tried to download something or watch an online video (youtube, or other) it took an eternity. Netflix continued to work but that definition was terrible. I tried to connect with a wired connection and once I restarted the modem and the router it worked fine for a couple of minutes but after that, the same problem continue to happen. I thought it was only in my apple devices but I checked my ps3 and tryed to download something and the same.

I ran several test with speedtest.net, every time I had a great signal and the test resulted at the broadband speed I pay for (5megs), that got me confused.

Avarege results:

ping: 10 Download: 4,9 megs Upload: 0,5 megs

I connected the devices one at the time directly form the modem to test and I found they were working as they should.

So I yesterday finally changed to my old router again, and the problem is no longer there.

Anybody with this problem.

Im not an expert on networking, but im really confused specially with the speed tests, and I would like to have an expensive router working and not as a brick.

Any ideas will be more than welcome.

Comment: Provided you don't have the revision 2 version of the router I suggest you place DD-WRT on it.  The factory firmware has lots of problems including running the radio in such a way it basically causes the router to overheat and restart.  While its still possible I suggest taking it back to the store.

Answer (score 1):

I also have E3200, but I don't have such problems. Try doing these:

- Reset all settings
- [Update the firmware to latest version](http://homesupport.cisco.com/en-us/support/routers/E3200)

If none of these helps, it might be something with hardware - you'll have to use the warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Have you performed a site survey and assured you do not have a nearby AP that is conflicting with your device?  It is possible the old AP used a different channel and the new one has a conflict.  A site survey would identify nearby devices and allow you to pick an unused channel and manually configure it.

It may be necessary to do several surveys at different times of the day.

As noted by @burtek, check your firmware and install latest.